# Store email styles in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, style

I have HTML emails where a ton of the styles repeat within and across emails.

I was thinking to store these in a data extension with "name" and "style" columns.

```
name: "paragraph", style: "font:18px Arial;"
```

Beyond incorporating an entire lookup for each instance of the style:

```
%%=Lookup("DefaultStyles","Style","Name","paragraph")=%%
```

Or assigning each new style to a variable individually before use, is there a "typical" method for accomplishing this?

Is there a better method for reusable CSS?

I'm also perfectly willing to use the server-side JS.

Comment: I believe it can be done, but really it can be accomplished probably quicker and easier by using a stylesheet and a good inliner prior to send...